# Extracting range of data with SED

Tags: linux

Format of file is

- 12000:P:1:14
- 12001 10000
- 12001 10500
- 12001 10800
- 12001 11000

What I need?
Using SED (using inline replace) that I extract range from (and included) 10500 to ( and included) 10800 (delete 12001 10000 and 12001 11000) and **create new file with same filename** that will look like this

- 12000:P:1:14
- 12001 10500
- 12001 10800

I do research and read many answers here , and only I found it work is 
sed -i '/10[0-4].../!d' *.file, but that is only partially good. As I can see only SED have (-i) option. Please some help

[Screenshot of data in Notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu60e.jpg)

Comment: By what criteria are you going to extract the lines? Always the first three? Less than 10736 in column2?

Comment: No, not always, this is just example: original have about 800 lines in one file, I need option to change range

Comment: Please, update your question with an explanation. It's quite unclear as it is now.

Comment: The "format of file" isn't clear.  Does your file contain lines in that form?  Are they literal bullet points?  Is the first line being retained because it is the first line or because of its format?  I don't think you'll have much luck with sed, as sed doesn't offer arithmetic operations.  I'd personally recommend using awk for this task, `awk '{if(NR==1 || ($2 >= 10500 && $2 <= 10800)){print $0}}'` would work for the filter.

Comment: I added screenshot, and as you can see it is simple text file without any bullet points ( I use them to preserve look of original file)
I bold text in my question: I dont need to print range : I need to put in file with same filename.

Comment: Also, remember that sed's `-i` option is [not standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), so you can't rely on it for complete portability.

Comment: Portability is not problem , it is for my personal use.

Comment: Pipe into a temp file and move it.  If your file here is "foo.txt", then use something like `awk '(NR==1 || ($2 >= 10500 && $2 <= 10800)){print $0}' foo.txt > foo.txt.new && mv foo.txt.new foo.txt` will do what you need.  You have these tools at your disposal; there's no reason to make things harder on yourself by avoiding powerful capabilities of the standard POSIX shell.

Comment: Your command in comment doesnot work, got error **file is not directory**.
I need to repeat that process 8000 times ( in same directory) @Taywee

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -ane 'print if 1 == $. || $F[1] >= 10500 && $F[1] <= 10800' file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits each line into the @F array
- `$.` is the input line number, so `1 == $.` is true for the header line
- `$F[1]` is the second column

Comment: This is not working, since it only prints range, not create new file(s), I can get same result using ` awk '{if (($2>10500) && ($2<10800))print $0}' *.npg  >>a.txt ` ,but that is not what I need @choroba

Comment: So pipe into a temp file and move it over the existing one.  Is there any reason you can't use file redirection and a separate move command?